# Simple Strings Confusion - Python34

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, conditional-statements

I am REALLY new to this and have been trying to figure this out for a day now. Having a bit of an issue with Python34. Here is my code:

```
myName = input('What is your name? ')
myVar = input("Enter your age please! ")

if(myName == "Jerome" and myVar == 22):
    print("Welcome back Pilot!")
    print(myName, myVar)
elif(myName == "Steven"):
    print("Steve is cool!")
    print(myName, myVar)
else:
    print("Hello there", myName)
    print(myName, myVar)
```

When I input- Jerome *enter* 22 *enter* into the console it still goes to the condition by printing:

```
Hello there Jerome
Jerome 22
```

Why is this happening? I also tried messing with the if statement by writing it like this: `if(myName == "Jerome") and (myVar == 22):` and I *still* got the same response.

Comment: You don't need parenthesis (`(` and `)`) with `if` statements in Python ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3, the [`input()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a *string*, but you are trying to compare `myVar` to an integer. Convert one or the other first. You can use the [`int()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) to do this:

```
myVar = int(input("Enter your age please! "))

if myName == "Jerome" and myVar == 22:
```

or use:

```
myVar = input("Enter your age please! ")

if myName == "Jerome" and myVar == "22":
```

Converting the user input to an integer has the advantage that you can make other comparisons, like smaller then, or greater then, etc.

You may want to read up on asking for user input with proper error handling, in that context. See [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).

Comment: Thank you Martijn for the help! I hope to see you again when I need help me on my future endeavors! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the culprit

```
myVar = input("Enter your age please! ")
```

`input` always returns a string

type cast it to `int` like

```
myVar = int(input("Enter your age please! "))
```

**OR**

Change your `if` condition as

```
if(myName == "Jerome" and myVar == "22"):
```

But this is an inferior method, as if you want to use your age somewher else, then it will become a problem

Comment: Thank you so much Bhargav! Sorry for my noobie-ness. This site is amazing!

Answer (score 0):

The method `input()` returns a string, which is a word or sentence, but you need to make it an integer, a whole number. To do that, just simply type instead of `input("Enter your age please")`, you need to type `int(input("Enter your age please"))`. That will turn it into an integer. ***Hope this helps!***